# Can I run grails 1.2-M3 with groovy 1.7 beta 1?

Tags: grails, groovy, version, environment

I have groovy 1.7 beta 1 in my path and GROOVY_HOME pointing to same groovy 1.7 beta 1 directory. I have installed grails 1.2-M3, and set GRAILS_HOME to point to  grails 1.2-M3.

I would like to try some groovy 1.7 features in my grails app, anonymous inner classes to be precise. I am receiving a compiler error even though this feature should be supported in groovy 1.7 beta 1.

I can see that grails includes groovy-all-1.6.4.jar in grails\lib directory.
In my setup, with grails 1.2-M3 and GROOVY_HOME pointing to same groovy 1.7 beta 1 directory and with groovy 1.7 beta 1 in my path, what is the version of groovy that grails is running with? What is the purpose of groovy-all-1.6.4.jar in grails\lib directory?

Finally, as I already asked in title, Can I run  grails 1.2-M3 with groovy 1.7 beta 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say you can't but also doesn't mention this groovy version. I would say it's a no-go unless you want to try it for a while and find a random incompatibility later.

Answer (score 1):

groovy-all-1.6.4.jar in the grails/lib is the groovy version that grails is using, grails does not use the environment variable GROOVY_HOME....

I don't know if you can use groovy1.7 beta in grails 1.2-m3, you can try downloading groovy-all1.7-b1.jar (if exists) and put it in grails/lib....

I think it won't work.....but you can try it.....

Comment: startGrails.bat does check for GROOVY_HOME:
:check_GROOVY_HOME
@rem Define GROOVY_HOME if not set
if "%GROOVY_HOME%" == "" set GROOVY_HOME=%DIRNAME%..
but now that you mention it, doesn't seem to make any use of it...